# C#でAccessにつなげるためのACE.oledbをインストールしても、実行時に登録されていないと出る。

Tags: c#, ms-access

お世話になります。

C#(.NetFramework4.5)で既存のAccessファイルに接続しようと、公式からaccessdatabaseengine.exeを
ダウンロードしてインストールしたのですが、実行時に登録されていないとエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
バージョンも、2016版の32bit(x64のついていない方)は確認したので、合っていると思うのですが、
原因がわかりません。

原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

下記がコードになります。

```
    //SQL作成
    DataTable resultDt = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.AppendLine("SELECT");
    sql.AppendLine("  *");
    sql.AppendLine("FROM M_社員");

    //Access接続準備
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbConnection cnAccess = new OleDbConnection();
    cnAccess.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.AccessCon;

    //Access接続開始
    cnAccess.Open();

    try
    {
        command.Connection = cnAccess;
        command.CommandText = sql.ToString();
        da.SelectCommand = command;

        //SQL実行 結果をデータテーブルに格納
        da.Fill(resultDt);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        command.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
        cnAccess.Close();
    }

    //結果出力
    for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex < resultDt.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
    {
        for (int colindex = 0; colindex < resultDt.Columns.Count; colindex++)
        {
            Console.Write(resultDt.Rows[rowindex][colindex] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

参考にさせていただいたのは、こちらのサイト様です。

https://hironimo.com/prog/c-sharp/c-accessdb/

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありきたりですが、プロジェクトのプロパティでビルドのプラットフォームや対象プラットフォームが`AnyCPU`になっていませんか？ 両方とも`x86`に固定した方が良いような気がしますが？

Comment: 無関係かもしれませんが、最新版は[Microsoft 365 Access Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9?ui=ja-JP&rs=ja-JP&ad=JP)らしいですよ。[Access runtime（アクセスランタイム版）の入手方法と使い方](https://msactrynext.com/archives/296.html), [Access2019ランタイムの動作確認方法おすすめ4つ](https://access-support.jp/column/access-2019-runtime-4-way/), [Access2019ランタイムを活用する](https://access-support.jp/column/access-2019-runtime/)

Comment: Runtimeも一度試したのですが、入れたところ、本来のAccessの起動の際に、ファイルをダブルクリックしてか、コマンドラインから入力してかでないと動きません等のメッセージが出るようになったため、削除しました。つのり、スタートメニューからAccessを直接起動することができなくなってしまったのです。

Comment: Visual Studio から ACE 経由で Access に接続できますか？　Visual Studio のウィザードは働きますか？　それが Yes なら ACE は 32-bit 版なので（32/64-bit 版は同じ PC 内に共存できません）、アプリが x86 であれば動くと思うのですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントに書いたのですが反応がないので回答欄に画像入りで書いておきます。

Visual Studio から ACE 経由で Access に接続できますか？　Visual Studio のウィザードは働きますか？　それが Yes なら ACE は 32-bit 版なので（32/64-bit 版は同じ PC 内に共存できません）、アプリが x86 であれば動くと思うのですが。

例えば、Visual Studio の「接続の追加」で Access を選び［詳細設定(V)...］をクリックして「詳細設定」の「Provider」をみて、以下の画像のように ACE が選択できればその PC には 32-bit 版 ACE がインストールされているはずです（Visual Studio は 32-bit なので 64-bit 版 ACE は使えません）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その先に進めていくと接続文字列も生成されるはずです。それを使って、アプリは x86 でコンパイルすればアプリからも問題なく Access に接続できるはずです。

Comment: すみません、今まで気が付きませんでした。いただいた方法で試してみたところ、つながるよぅになりました。やはり64ビットでやってしまったのが原因のようでした。お礼が遅れ、申し訳ありませんでした。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

スクリーンショットのAccessConのMicrosoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0って文字列はどこから持ってきたんでしょう？ダウンロードページの説明にあるプロバイダー引数と明らかに違うようですけど。

[Microsoft Access データベース エンジン 2016 再頒布可能コンポーネント](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

多分接続文字列が間違ってるか何かだと思いますが、VisualStudioから"ツール">"データベースへ接続"で接続してみて接続文字列を確認してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。16の数字は、そこだけ自分で12から書き換えました。ちなみに、2010の方の本来の12でも試しましたが、結果は同じでした。そのため、やはり新しい方でないと認識しないのではと判断しました。そのほかはすべてサイト様にある通りの手段です。

Comment: ちなみにOLEDBプロバイダー列挙して出てきてますかね？ https://hardsoft.at.webry.info/201310/article_9.html